# Аналог `os.path.commonpath()` в `pathlib`

Tags: python, pathlib

Я пытаюсь использовать библиотеку `pathlib` вместо `os.path` где это возможно.

Скажите, есть ли аналог функции `commonpath()` в этой библиотеке? Я не нашёл. Если встроенной функции нет, я не буду писать код для этого, а просто использую `os.path.commonpath()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Похоже что нет, в таблице соответствия этой функций нет: [Correspondence to tools in the os module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module).

Но в документации [`os.path.commonpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonpath) указано, что она поддерживает path-like objects, т.е. в том числе объекты `Path` из pathlib, поэтому если у вас везде в коде используется pathlib, конвертировать пути в строки перед передачей в `commonpath` не нужно (правда возвращает путь в виде строки, результат нужно будет обернуть в `Path` при необходимости).